# Unable to import multithreaded Python module.

Tags: python, multithreading, import, module, multiprocessing

This is the multithreaded code I'm trying to import as a module. It works fine when I run it as a stand alone file. It simply just prints out a list of numbers. All I change is which main() is commented out. I think that the problem might be that the imported code is calling itself as a module after the reader file has already called it as a module.

threadtest.py

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array
import time
import sys

def f(n, a):
    n.value = 3.1415927
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = -a[i]

def is_prime(x, top):
    for j in range(2,int(top**.5 + 1)):
        if x%j == 0:
            return False
    return True

def f1(top, c):
    print('test f1')
    for i in range(2,top):
        if is_prime(i,top):
            c.value = c.value + 1

def f3(c1,c2):
    for k in range(0,20):
        time.sleep(1)  # 1 second
        sys.stdout.write(str(c1.value) + '|' + str(c2.value) + '\n')  
        sys.stdout.flush()  

def main():

count1 = Value('d', 0)
count2 = Value('d', 0)
#arr = Array('i', range(10))
p1 = Process(target=f1, args=(1000000, count1))
p2 = Process(target=f1, args=(1000000, count2))
p3 = Process(target=f3, args=(count1, count2))

p1.start()
p2.start()
p3.start()

p1.join()
print('p1.join()')
p2.join()
print('p2.join()')
p3.join()
print('p3.join()')

print(count1.value)
print(count2.value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('grovetest is being run as main')
    #main()
else:
    print('grovetest is being run as module')
    main()
```

This is the code that imports the multithreaded module and attempts to read the output.

readertest.py

```
import threadtest

def main(fname):

    try:

        p = subprocess.Popen(fname, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        print('success')
        return p.communicate()  # this gets you pipe values

    except Exception as e:

        return 'error'+str(e)

    else:

        return "else"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(threadtest)
```

Here is the error that is produced when I run the readertest.py

```
grovetest is being run as module
grovetest is being run as module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 106, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 226, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 278, in _fixup_main_from_path
    run_name="__mp_main__")
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 240, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\documents\python projects\multitest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import grovetest
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\documents\python projects\grovetest.py", line 56, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\documents\python projects\grovetest.py", line 37, in main
    p1.start()
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 212, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 313, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 34, in __init__
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 144, in get_preparation_data
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 137, in _check_not_importing_main
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.''')
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 106, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 226, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 278, in _fixup_main_from_path
    run_name="__mp_main__")
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 240, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\documents\python projects\multitest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import grovetest
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\documents\python projects\grovetest.py", line 56, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\documents\python projects\grovetest.py", line 37, in main
    p1.start()
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 212, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 313, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 34, in __init__
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 144, in get_preparation_data
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 137, in _check_not_importing_main
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.''')
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
grovetest is being run as module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 106, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 226, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 278, in _fixup_main_from_path
    run_name="__mp_main__")
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 240, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\documents\python projects\multitest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import grovetest
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\documents\python projects\grovetest.py", line 56, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\documents\python projects\grovetest.py", line 37, in main
    p1.start()
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 212, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 313, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 34, in __init__
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 144, in get_preparation_data
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 137, in _check_not_importing_main
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.''')
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
grovetest is being run as module
p1.join()
p2.join()
p3.join()
0.0
0.0
```

I'm new to this. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're violating a significant Windows-specific constraint called out [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows):

> Make sure that the main module can be safely imported by a new Python interpreter without causing unintended side effects (such a starting a new process).

One flaw in the paragraph I just quoted is that it says "the main module" when it should say "*every* module", but most people don't try to run complex code from imported modules and thus don't run across this issue.  In your case, what happens is that `readertest` imports `grovetest`, which invokes the multiprocessing code, which fires up a new Python interpreter on `grovetest` using the special Windows multiprocess bootstrap system, which fires up the multiprocessing code, which detects that it's being fired up under the special bootstrap case and aborts:

```
(start)
readertest:
    import grovetest

 => grovetest
    import multiprocessing
     => multiprocessing: define some stuff

 => grovetest
    if __name__ == '__main__': # it's not equal
        ... # so we skip this
    else:
        print('grovetest is being run as module') # prints
        main() # calls main
    ...
    p1 = Process(target=f1, args=(1000000, count1)) # calls multiprocessing module

      => new process
         import grovetest # multiprocessing does this using its magic bootstrap
         ...
         if __name__ == '__main__': # it's not
             ...
         else:
             print(...)
             ...
             p1 = Process(...)
```

At this point the inner `Process` code detects the constraint violation and raises the first error.  This terminates the inner process entirely, and we're back to the outer process that does `p2 = Process(...)`, which kicks off the same error again, and so on.

To fix this, you *must not* call your `main` in `grovetest` when `grovetest` is imported as a module.  Instead, call `grovetest.main` *later*, from `readertest`.  That will allow the special bootstrap magic (in the `multiprocessing` module, run up when you invoke `multiprocessing.Process`) to import `grovetest` in the new process.  Once this new process has finished importing `grovetest`, it will wait for instructions from its parent process (the other Python interpreter, where *you* called `multiprocessing.Process`, from your `readertest` code calling `grovetest.main`).  Those instructions will be to invoke function `f1` (from `target=f1`) with the supplied arguments.